# ObjectId.ToString not working in projection (LINQ)

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

I get an exception when executing this code:

```
List<TenantSelectorDto> foundSelectors = null;
//.....
foundSelectors = tenants
.Where(filter)
.Select(ts => new TenantSelectorDto
{
    Id = ts.Id.ToString(),
    Name = ts.Name,
    ShortName =  ts.ShortName,
    TenantCode = ts.TenantCode,
})
.ToList();
```

The exception is:

`NotSupportedException, Message: ToString of type System.Object is not supported in the expression tree {document}{_id}.ToString().`

`Id` in the DTO is defined as **string** while the `Id` of the `Tenant` object is a MongoDB `ObjectId`. The DTO is part of a REST API and I **do not want to force consumers to link with the entire MongoDB driver libraries just because of the data type `ObjectId`**.

Is this a bug or why does .ToString not work when using in a projection?

Comment: did you solve this error in join?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a LINQ problem! Instead of using LINQ I tried to use the Aggregation Framework and here it works as expected!

```
var filterDefinition = Builders<Tenant>.Filter.Where(<Build whatever filter you need here>);

var foundSelectors = tenantCollection
    .Find(filterDefinition)
    .Project(ts => new TenantSelectorDto
    {
        Id = ts.Id.ToString(),
        Name = ts.Name,
        ShortName = ts.ShortName,
        TenantCode = ts.TenantCode,
    })
    .ToList();
```

Does the trick **without** exception!

Don't know if this is a general LINQ problem or a problem of the MongoDB LINQ implementation though.